# Elastic APM Agent Access Denied with AccessControlException

Tags: java, sonarqube, elastic-stack, elastic-apm

I am implementing apm agent to sonarqube and I can connect to apm server using curl

curl -v "" returns 200

**Command:**

sudo java -jar apm-agent-attach-standalone.jar --include '.*sonar.*' ---config config_file=elasticapm.properties

**Command output:**

It shows agent as attached

**Logfile:**

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader")
        at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:897)
        at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:322)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:393)
        at co.elastic.apm.agent.premain.AgentMain.loadAndInitializeAgent(AgentMain.java:174)
        at co.elastic.apm.agent.premain.AgentMain.init(AgentMain.java:122)
        at co.elastic.apm.agent.premain.AgentMain.agentmain(AgentMain.java:67)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallAgentmain(InstrumentationImpl.java:535)
2021-04-21 11:11:55,561 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] ERROR co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - Error trying to connect to APM Server. Some details about SSL configurations corresponding the current connection are logged at INFO level.
2021-04-21 11:11:55,561 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] ERROR co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - Failed to handle event of type JSON_WRITER with this error: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2021-04-21 11:11:55,561 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - Backing off for 36 seconds (+/-10%)
2021-04-21 11:11:55,709 [elastic-apm-configuration-reloader] WARN  co.elastic.apm.agent.shaded.stagemonitor.configuration.ConfigurationOption - Error in Attachment configuration: no protocol: 8200 Default value 'http://localhost:8200' for 'server_url' will be applied.
2021-04-21 11:11:56,176 [elastic-apm-server-reporter] ERROR co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler - Error trying to connect to APM Server. Some details about SSL configurations corresponding the current connection are logged at INFO level.
```

**Query:**

It shows access denied exception ...**How to fix this?**

**Note:**
For server_url i tried using properties file, --config server_url, --args server_url which usually works

**elasticapm.properties:**

```
service_name=sonar-service
server_url=https://elk:8200
log_file=/var/log/elastic-apm.log
```

Comment: Can you provide your `elasticapm.properties` file?

Comment: Sure...I have added...Also I heard I need to add the apm agent to jvm policy for access...Also need to try with 1.23 version of apm agent.. Let me try and post the results here

Comment: Also make sure that your APM server is configured to use SSL. Your endpoint is set to `https://elk:8200` and your logs are saying that the connection was refused — and there are SSL errors included. Maybe try without the SSL?

`http://elk:8200`

Comment: I have restarted the application then reattached the agent 1.22v, now it works. Thanks @RicardoFerreira... Sometimes the configuration options are not working using dynamic